# "An event is starting" often means started and long since done in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

Chat has this really great feature that notifies you of events that are about to begin in rooms that you participate by sliding down a small notification at the top of the screen saying something like this:

> An event is starting in [room], [event name] in [minutes]

You then have the option to click and dismiss it. However, it persists *until* you click to dismiss it.

Given that:

- It knows how soon the event is going to start
- It knows when the event is scheduled to end

... can we please:

- Change the text to "An event has begun in [room] ...." while underway
- Remove the notice entirely if not dismissed after the event has concluded?

This seems like it could be accomplished by just starting a timer. I know that it's a really minor thing, I just noticed today that almost every time I see one of those notifications, whatever prompted it is long since over. I love seeing them, but I wish I could see them only when they matter.

Comment: While at it, would also make sense to delete the notification sent to the inbox in case the event ended without you ever seeing the notification, same way comment notifications are removed when the parent post or comment is deleted.